# How to plot ROC curve for weka multilayerperceptron?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on an image classification project I use multilayerperceptron,how do I plot ROC curve.I use weka's perceptron.

Answer (score 1):

From [University of Waikato WEKA wiki](https://weka.wikispaces.com/ROC+curves):

> The class used for calculating the ROC and also the AUC (= area under the curve) is [weka.classifiers.evaluation.ThresholdCurve](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/ThresholdCurve.html).

Comment: I used ThresholdCurve for ploting but what should be the input ,is it the arff file containing the validation data set ?The results I obtained looks strange.I works on multiclass classification and need to plot the curve for each of the class.